# questions about password_hash()

Tags: php, security, hash, passwords, bcrypt

I just have a little question about the password_hash() function, does it create a ramdom salt for me? I mean I don't have to specify something like this:

```
'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)
```

Because I suppose that the function creates a **random and different** salt for **EACH** of the password?

Another question, if I use `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` in the function password_hash in this way : `password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)` is like to use `password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_BCRYPT)` ?

Comment: I would suggest pulling out the second question into a new post.

Comment: it's all in the manuals Pablo.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP should have [read the very fine manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: How [Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=php+hash+password) helps you to find [this guide](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)  !!

Comment: why did you answered anyway? is stackoverflow.com of yours? or you are the master of the web? such a person you must be.

Comment: I answered because you hadn't read the manual @PabloTobar. Just trying to be helpful.

Comment: And you should *never* set the salt manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salt is automatically generated, but you can specify your own in the options. 
As of PHP 5.5 the default algorithm is BCRYPT but it can change over time.

Answer (score 1):

***password_hash()*** will automatically generate a random salt each time it is called, unless you manually specify one in the third argument, ***$options***.

***PASSWORD_DEFAULT*** is equivalent to ***PASSWORD_BCRYPT*** as of PHP 5.5, however that may change in the future. ***You should NOT assume that PASSWORD_DEFAULT will always use the bcrypt algorithm in future versions of PHP***.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs if you don't specify any salt it will generate a random one each time:

> salt - to manually provide a salt to use when hashing the password.
>   Note that this will override and prevent a salt from being
>   automatically generated.
>
> If omitted, a random salt will be generated by password_hash() for
>   each password hashed. This is the intended mode of operation.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 0):

From [the very fine manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) -

> If omitted, a random salt will be generated by password_hash() for each password hashed. This is the intended mode of operation.

Additionally (your second question) more from [the very fine manual](http://php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php) -

> PASSWORD_DEFAULT (integer)
>
> The default algorithm to use for hashing if no algorithm is provided. This may change in newer PHP releases when newer, stronger hashing algorithms are supported.
>
> ...
>
> **Values for this constant:**
>
> **PHP 5.5.0 - PASSWORD_BCRYPT**